# How to access Enum of arrays

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have two sets of Products

```
public enum ProductType {

    FOUNDATION_OR_PAYMENT ("946", "949", "966"),
    NOVA_L_S_OR_SESAM ("907", "222");

    private String[] type;

    ProductType(String... type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then given a value"actualProductType" I need to check if it is part of the productType ..How do I do this  ..

```
isAnyProductTypes(requestData.getProductType(), ProductType.NOVA_L_S_SESAM)
```

---

```
 public boolean isAnyProductTypes(String actualProductType, ProductType productTypes) {
        return Arrays.stream(productTypes).anyMatch(productType -> productType.equals(actualProductType));
    }
```

I get an error at this part Arrays.stream(productTypes)

Comment: Something is off with the terminology here. Is a product type a String or an array of strings? They can't both be "product type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your enum does not change, you could build a `Map` inside it for faster look-up:

```
public enum ProductType {


    FOUNDATION_OR_PAYMENT("946", "949", "966"),
    NOVA_L_S_OR_SESAM("907", "222");

    static Map<String, ProductType> MAP;

    static {
        MAP = Arrays.stream(ProductType.values())
                    .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.type)
                                        .map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getValue, Entry::getKey));
    }

    private String[] type;

    ProductType(String... type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isAnyProductTypes(String actualProductType, ProductType productTypes) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(MAP.get(actualProductType))
                       .map(productTypes::equals)
                       .orElse(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change the type to `Set<String>` and the constructor as well

```
ProductType(String... type) {
    this.type = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(type));
}
```

and the lookup will be very simple

```
return productType.getType().contains(requestData.getProductType())
```

Comment: not really what the question meant I would say. this changes the contract of the expected api the user has shared.

Comment: @Naman it solves the problem. The OP did not state that he can't modify the enum, it's certainly better than doing the lookup every time and it's simplest solution ... no need for stream really

Comment: storing `String[]` as `Set<String>` wouldn't solve the problem is what I wanted to point out. It's just an attribute attached with each type. To check none of the types has a value, you would still have to iterate through all such types and check amongst there sets if the value is contained.

Comment: @Naman if you look at the `isAnyProductTypes` signature you'll see that it receives a single `ProductType` so he wants to search inside a given enum value and not all

Comment: well I would say the question is unclear in that aspect then for the type, `productTypes` it reads..